# React Native naming collision error when running packager, caused by "lodash" and "yeoman-generator"

Tags: javascript, npm, react-native, jestjs, react-native-cli

## Description

In my project I am using `"react-native": "0.36.0"` and among the dependencies:

- `"lodash": "^4.15.0"`
- `"yeoman-generator": "^0.24.1"`

When using versions higher than `"^3.10.1"` for `"lodash"` and `"0.21.2"` for `"yeoman-generator"` I get naming collisions on `"lodash"`, `"inquirer"` and `"cli-width"` when running packager.

## Reproduction

Have the dependencies described above and run: `react-native start --reset-cache`

Result:

```
jest-haste-map: @providesModule naming collision:
Duplicate module name: inquirer
  Paths: /CoolProject/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/inquirer/package.json collides with /CoolProject/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/inquirer/package.json

This warning is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same name across two different files.
jest-haste-map: @providesModule naming collision:
  Duplicate module name: lodash
  Paths: /CoolProject/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/lodash/package.json collides with /CoolProject/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/lodash/package.json

This warning is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same name across two different files.
jest-haste-map: @providesModule naming collision:
  Duplicate module name: cli-width
  Paths: /CoolProject/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/yeoman-generator/node_modules/cli-width/package.json collides with /CoolProject/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/cli-width/package.json

This warning is caused by a @providesModule declaration with the same name across two different files.
```

## Solution

Using the same versions for `"lodash"` and `"yeoman-generator"` as the ones used in `react-native@0.36.0` (i.e. `"^3.10.1"` for `"lodash"` and `"0.21.2"` for `"yeoman-generator"`) fixes the issue, but changing them is really not an option for me at the moment, especially because `"yeoman-generator"` is the dependency of another dependency.
Is there any other possible fix?

Thanks!

## Update

More details about this issue can be found in the `react-native` Gihub issue I posted: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11200

## Update 2

Upgrading `react-native` to 0.39 solves the problem. The actual fix seems to be the removal of the apparently unused (and maybe outdated) `yeoman-generator` dependency: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/1fd7a574ba538d05da4be841c84a70766464ec13

Comment: What version of npm are you using?

Comment: npm v3.10.8 and node v7.0.0

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you switch from `npm` to `yarn` when installing modules or setting up projects using React Native. A simple `npm install` will usually close this issue without damaging your project's configuration.

`npm install` will notify you some of your modules are either deprecated or set up on a different version from the React Native ones and do what it takes to fix it. Also, if you wish to really clean up your configuration, notice the `npm WARN gentlyRm` warnings about packages that are put aside but not removed.